# How to set results from sqlite to array NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, sqlite

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
NSString *ask = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM users"];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *query_statement = [ask UTF8String];
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK){
        {
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB, query_statement, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    NSString *nameField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

                }

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                sqlite3_close(_DB);
            }
        }
```

I want to set those result above to NSMUtableArray like this example:

```
 totalStrings =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"xxx",@"xxx",@"xxx", nil];
```

What should I do ?

=================UP DATE ALL CODE =======================
Here is the aditonal code to make it easy to see. I really don´t know what I have done wrong.

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *totalStrings;
    NSMutableArray *filteredStrings;
    BOOL isFiltered;
}
@property(strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *entries;


@end


@implementation ViewController;
@synthesize entries;


- (void)viewDidLoad {



  //  totalStrings =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ggg",@"gggggg", nil];
  //  NSLog(@"%@",totalStrings);


    NSMutableArray* result=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *ask = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM users"];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *query_statement = [ask UTF8String];
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK){
        {
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB, query_statement, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
            {
                while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                {
                    NSString *nameField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

                    //add your namefield here.
                    [result addObject:nameField];
                     totalStrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];



                }

                sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                sqlite3_close(_DB);
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",totalStrings);

        //AND PUT THOSE RESULTS INTO THIS ARRAY ( I WILL USE THIS LATER)
        //I want it to be this format:  totalStrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"test1",@"test2",@"test3", nil];


    }
```

Comment: Hey you are putting `totalStrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];` in wrong place. put outside all the loop just above the `NSLog` you have put.

Comment: Hi I have done it, and now I get nothing:
Here is the result :
2015-04-21 07:50:31.792 SQLexample[17542:299715] (
)

Comment: Can you put `NSLog(@"User - %@", nameField);` above `[result addObject:nameField];` and see if you get any log or, not.

Comment: Hi I did it, and the result is : 2015-04-21 08:19:46.454 SQLexample[18800:313530] (
)

But Now I found that...If I put your code into the - (IBAction)find:(id)sender {...} the result is appear. Seems like I can not do it immediately right after the app is loaded. Have I done something wrong or incompltet ?

Comment: No nothing wrong, but you should put all in a function, and use `[self performSelector:@selector(fetchData) withObject:nil afterDelay:.2];` to call the function from viewDidLoad, it should work.

Comment: I got it now,  alll because I have the dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);  and its connection below your code. That is why the data can not be fetch..Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should work in case you want to get all namefields in array

```
NSMutableArray* result=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *ask = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM users"];
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        const char *query_statement = [ask UTF8String];
        const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK){
            {
                if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB, query_statement, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
                    {
                        NSString *nameField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

                        //add your namefield here.
                       [result addObject:nameField];
                    }

                    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                    sqlite3_close(_DB);
                }
            }
```

In the end you can do

```
totalStrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer iphonic
But I need the variable "totalstrings" which content this array to use it after.
How to do this ?

Comment: You can do `totalStrings=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];`

Comment: Hi I did it but i got result (null) :(

Comment: Can you confirm that you are able to fetch data by your code? What is the data type of `totalStrings`? Is this `NSString` or, `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: Hi, I have update the code. 
Yes I have put data into database. 
I don´t know what have I done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Create and Alloc New NSMutableArray totalStrings and add nameField in the totalStrings in While Loop.

```
NSMutableArray *totalStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In while loop

```
[totalStrings addObject:nameField];
```

Comment: Hi where should I put the first line ?
I have put it in @interface ViewController 
And I get error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it like this,

```
-(NSArray *)list_totalStrings
{
    NSMutableArray *totalStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *ask = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT name FROM users"]; //Make sure field and table names are proper
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *query_statement = [ask UTF8String];
    const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_DB) == SQLITE_OK){
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_DB, query_statement, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *nameField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                [totalStrings addObject:nameField];
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(_DB);
            NSLog(@"%@",totalStrings);
            return totalStrings;
        }
        else
            return nil;
    }
    else
        return nil;
}
```

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier 'list_totalStringd'

Comment: Where you have find `list_totalStringd` in my code, it is `list_totalStrings`.